# PgAdmin 4: Save Server Connection Details

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Running pgAdmin 4.2.0 in a Docker container using the image `dpage/pgadmin4`, I notice that server connections are not being saved.

The container is created with the volume mapping:

```
./data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
```

When the docker container is restarted, or when a user re-login to the dashboard, all the previously entered server connection details are gone.

How can we ensure that the connection details are properly saved?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69189740/4695280

Answer (score 19):

For anyone still with this issue, I got it working using container folder /var/lib/pgadmin, so in your yml volume:

```
./data/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you start it with `docker run dpage/pgadmin4` or `docker start {containerID}`?

When I was doing it with `docker run` I had similar issues as you, but when I changed to `docker start` all connection details were normally there (even after computer reboot).

Comment: Hello, welcome! I used `docker-compose up`, so I guess its equivalent to `docker run`.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Then you can try with `docker compose start` which also just restarts already created containers instead of creating new (as in case of `up`). If that does not help, please post your `yml` file that you are using with `docker compose`.